# CUBE Statement to merge rows into one row - SQL 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a Table like this:

dwh_data:

```
 DATETIME        FK_FEDERAL_STATE     FK_ACCOMODATION      ARRIVALS     NIGHTS
--------------- -------------------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
    200010               W96-3           60                8012      24724
    200010               W96-3           61                2283       7715
    200010               W96-3           86                 674       4171
    200010               W96-3           87                 329       1998
```

HINT: Datetime = first 4 numbers = year +  last two numbers = month

This is my statement:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(datetime,1,4), dwh_accomodations.name, SUM(NIGHTS)
FROM dwh_data
     JOIN DWH_ACCOMODATIONS
        ON dwh_data.fk_accomodation = DWH_ACCOMODATIONS.CODE
  GROUP BY CUBE(datetime, dwh_accomodations.name)
  ORDER BY datetime;
```

My statement gives me this result:

```
 SUBS NAME                                               SUM(NIGHTS)
---- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
1998 ACC_TYPE1                                               104506
1998 ACC_TYPE2                                               150524
1998 ACC_TYPE1                                               399419
```

The problem there is that there are duplicate names for one year. SUBS = Year

I want to get all names with the same value into one row. The result should look like this then:

```
 SUBS NAME                                               SUM(NIGHTS)
---- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
1998 ACC_TYPE1                                               504925
1998 ACC_TYPE2                                               150524
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also group by the year?

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(datetime,1,4) AS year
, acco.name
, SUM(NIGHTS) AS Total
FROM dwh_data AS data
JOIN DWH_ACCOMODATIONS AS acco
  ON acco.CODE = data.fk_accomodation
GROUP BY CUBE(SUBSTR(datetime,1,4), acco.name)
ORDER BY year;
```

**Simplyfied test**

> ```
> create table test(
>  yearmonth char(6), 
>  grp char(1), 
>  col number
> )
> ```

> ```
> insert all
> into test (yearmonth, grp, col) values ('202110', 'A', 10)
> into test (yearmonth, grp, col) values ('202111', 'A', 20)
> into test (yearmonth, grp, col) values ('202012', 'B', 40)
> select 1 from dual;
> ```

> ```
> select SUBSTR(yearmonth,1,4) as year, grp, sum(col) as tot
> from test
> group by SUBSTR(yearmonth,1,4), grp
> order by year
> ```

> ```
> YEAR | GRP | TOT
> :--- | :-- | --:
> 2020 | B   |  40
> 2021 | A   |  30
> ```

> ```
> select SUBSTR(yearmonth,1,4) as year, grp, sum(col) as tot
> from test
> group by rollup(SUBSTR(yearmonth,1,4), grp)
> order by year
> ```
>
> ```
> YEAR | GRP  | TOT
> :--- | :--- | --:
> 2020 | B    |  40
> 2020 | null |  40
> 2021 | A    |  30
> 2021 | null |  30
> null | null |  70
> ```

> ```
> select SUBSTR(yearmonth,1,4) as year, grp, sum(col) as tot
> from test
> group by cube(SUBSTR(yearmonth,1,4), grp)
> order by year
> ```
>
> ```
> YEAR | GRP  | TOT
> :--- | :--- | --:
> 2020 | B    |  40
> 2020 | null |  40
> 2021 | A    |  30
> 2021 | null |  30
> null | A    |  30
> null | B    |  40
> null | null |  70
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e3ee128b5700437865b3ee07474bb597)*

Comment: I'm getting this error with your SQL statement: The extract source does not contain the specified extract field.

Comment: Probably because you cannot extract year from datetime. Datetime is a number 200012 like this. With SUBSTR(DATETIME,1,4) I get the year of DATETIME. The  problem is that I cannot use SUBSTR in the GROUP BY

Comment: Ah right, it's a number. The name tricked me.

Comment: Are you looking forward to update your answer? :)

Comment: Fixed, and added a simple fiddle.